# How to check user's perms in a logical way?

Tags: permissions, facebook-javascript-sdk

At one point in time, my FB app only asked for basic info.  Now, I need birthdays and photos.

With user already **logged in** and app **authorized**, What is a good/sane way to:

1. Check for necessary perms
2. Pop the login dialog (if missing perms)
3. Know that the user accepted new perms

Right now, I have to make a call to fetch perms, pop dialog, check perms again. Is that the only way to do it? I'm **doing this client-side**, and it's callback/processor soup.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a javascript example for publish_stream.  It is a callback mess and should be refactored for readability.

```
FB.api('/me/permissions', function (response) {
    if (response && response.data && response.data.length) {
        var permissions = response.data.shift();
        if (!permissions.publish_stream) {
            FB.login(function (response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    FB.api('/me/permissions', function (response) {
                        if (response && response.data && response.data.length) {
                            permissions = response.data.shift();
                            if (permissions.publish_stream) {
                              // do whatever...you go the permission
                            } else {
                              // They did not grant permissions
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, { scope: "publish_stream" });
        }
    }
});
```